# .htaccess Redirect any file in directory to index.php of same directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm creating a blog, and would like to use the title of each entry as the URL.
The blog is pulling from a database and has code in a single php file to display the blog entry.

I would like any url like, domain.com/blog/this-is-the-title.html to redirect to 
domain.com/blog/index.php
BUT, keep the URL in the browser bar as the original url.

EDIT...

**domain.com/blog/anything-that-is-here.html**

should redirect to **domain.com/blog/index.php**

But, still show **domain.com/blog/anything-that-is-here.html** in the browser address bar.

I hope this makes sense.

Hoping this is something that can be accomplished in.htaccess.

Thanks!
Rick

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the `rewrite` function from Apache.

Something like this should work for your case:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?title=$1
```

An URL like `domain.com/blog/test-title` will internally call your `index.php` with `$_GET['title'] = "test-title"`.

Comment: Thank you Furkan.  Should this also work if the url is something like domain.com/blog/this-is-the-title.html  (It doesn't seem to be workiing)

Comment: What error message do you get? Maybe add a test echo to your php file to see if it gets executed at all

Comment: No error is shown. It just doesn't redirect.  I put a simele "Hello" in index.php, but nothing.

Comment: It won't redirect visible. It will just internally call the index.php while showing the original url with .html in the browser. Is the .htaccess and your index.php in the same directory? What's your server configuration? Local server on Windows or remote Server?

Comment: No, the index.php I'd like to use is also in the /blog/ directory.  The .htaccess I'm editing is in the root.

Comment: Please try putting them both in the blog directory

Comment: I might have another issue going on. Let me troubleshoot my .htaccess file and try again.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem! Please mark my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Not to totally change things up, but I think this approach will work better with my current .htaccess setup.   If a user lands on www.domain.com/blog/any-title-at-all.html, it will redirect them to www.domain.com/blog_item.html.

Comment: Well it is difficult to help you, if we don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. In your post you wanted a rewrite to your index.php. Now you don't want to use php at all and just want a file mapping?

Answer (score -1):

Try using [P]

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / domain.com/blog/index.php [P]
```

Comment: Would this go into the /blog/directory?

Comment: Try the edited one, hope it should give you your desired answer.

Comment: The Proxy function is unnecessary here, because the index.php is on the same server.

Comment: Why would you use a proxy for the same server??